# Workaround for Bug EXTJS-22715 enableTextSelection: true has no effect inside Window

Tags: extjs, extjs-grid, extjs6.2

The `enableTextSelection` attribute doesn't work when grid is inside a window. The following code has no effect on the grid.

```
viewConfig: {
    enableTextSelection: true
}
```

See this fiddle for a demonstration: 
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1jg2
and this sencha forum thread: https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?331120

The version ExtJs 6.2.0 is affected, but the problem is resolved in ExtJs 6.2.1.

The problem is that there is not ExtJs 6.2.1 GPL release yet.

Is there a workaround for this problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have fixed your issue please check this [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1s7e&view/editor). Here I have added **getRowClass()** in viewConfig according to given enableTextSelection config. This solved the issue.Reply if any concerns.
Below is code :

```
id: 'sampleGrid',
viewConfig: {
    enableTextSelection: true,
    getRowClass: function (record, rowIndex, rowParams, store) {
       var enableTextSelection=Ext.getCmp('sampleGrid').viewConfig.enableTextSelection;
       if(enableTextSelection)
        return "x-selectable";
    }
},
```

There is even a simpler way, without adding an `id` to the grid (because inside `getRowClass` `this` refers to the view itself):

```
viewConfig: {
    enableTextSelection: true,
    getRowClass: function () {
        return this.enableTextSelection ? 'x-selectable' : '';
    }
},
```

Comment: Thank you. It looks good. I will test it in my app tomorrow. Please include the code in your answer, so that it my help others even when the fiddle will no longer exist.